# SVG: fill pattern with holes

Tags: svg

In SVG, I want to use a fill pattern but leave "holes" in the pattern where other shapes are drawn, like this [example](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/s6xyt) (which wasn't drawn with SVG). I think I'm supposed to use clipping and/or masking but I'm not seeing how.

The whole SVG will be superimposed on an image that needs to be visible through the "holes" (and through the background pattern). So I can't obscure the image by filling the holes with a solid color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 'compound paths'. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h5NMP/) fiddle for a very simple example.

[image]

When you have the pattern, apply  to overlay on image.

The reference cited in answer by Robert Longson is really worth to read.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this without using clipping by using even-odd filling, alternatively you could use a clip-path [both approaches are described here](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#masks_clips).